# Glassfish docroot URL rewrite rule to support angular router

Tags: java, glassfish

I am currently using a Glassfish 4 Server to host a web API. I have developed an angular front end that I want Glassfish to host.

The angular front end uses a javascript routing object which requires a server rewrite rule to work.

This is the current `web.config` file I am using with IIS to serve my angular code

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/v1/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I set up glassfish to do the same thing for the docroot web server?